# Undo a single iab abbreviation expansion

Tags: abbreviations

Vim has an "abbreviation" feature built-in that can automatically expand certain abbreviations:

```
:iab SE Stack Exchange
```

[image]

However, sometimes I might want to type "SE" *without* it expanding to "Stack Exchange."

Is there any way to undo a single abbreviation and insert only the original, unabbreviated text? If not, can I add something to my `.vimrc` to enable a key shortcut or other method of doing so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you typing SE hit `CTRL-v` and then `spacebar` to insert space character.
See `:h i_CTRL-v` for details.

Comment: Ctrll+Q also works if your terminal doesn't eat it.